# How long is the duration of a shelltoast

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a shell toast that is working great... however, I have read that it is only supposed to "stay active" for 10 seconds...

My toast never goes away until I swipe it off or click it.

Is there some kind of dismiss that I can invoke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShellToasts are shown for ten seconds after you call ShellToast.Show(). If the user taps and holds on the toast, it will not be dismissed until they swipe it away or release.

There is no way to "dismiss" a toast notification. If you are developing for Windows Phone 8.1, there are additional APIs available to manage how toast notifications are managed in the notification center.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/11/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-notifications.aspx

Comment: Bailey...  thanks for the links... I have seen these... however the toasts on in my program (DEBUG builds) stay up indefinitely.  Is this a debug problem ? ( I would tend to say no, but then again, nothing is certain in the windows world )